# CTRL+ shortcuts doesn't work after compiz-manager installation

Tags: 12.04, gnome, compiz, shortcut-keys, gnome-classic

It was working on Gnome Fallback/Classic. But after `compiz-manager` package installation, I lost <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + shortcut keys, they don't work anymore.

For example, in web browser typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on some text makes it gray, and don't get it copied. Deleting `compiz-manager` and reinstalling gnome didn't solve the problem.

However, on Gnome Shell 3 all works fine.

Please, help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue a little while back, and after going a little crazy I found that it was a small silly issue - I accidentally un-checked the Gnome Compatibility option in the CompizConfig settings manager. 
The Gnome Compatibility option is what makes Compiz compatible with the Gnome desktop environment. 
Hope this helps solve your issue :)

Comment: I have Gnome Compatibility box checked all time. Thats doesn't solved my problem.